# why is ColdFusion's Epoch Time Dec 30, 1899?

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset x = createTimespan(0,0,0,0)>
    <cfset epoch = createDateTime(1899,12,30,0,0,0)>
    <cfset date = epoch + x>
    #date# #dateFormat(date)# #timeFormat(date)#
</cfoutput>
```

output:

> 0 30-Dec-99 12:00 AM

What's so significant about Dec 30, 1899?

Comment: Automation date format?http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/05/54806.aspx OLE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said, it is probably related to the COM/OLE automation date format; its first version was written in Microsoft VC++ back in 1995 ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion#Other_features)), and it's plausible that it exploited OLE features.

The OLE datetime type, in turn, was influenced by the decision of using VBA into Excel.

Excel had to be backwards-compatible with Lotus 123, which considered 1900 as a leap year (but years divisible by 100 are leap years only if they are divisible by 400); while its day 1 was officially 1/1/1900, it considered 29/02/1900 as an existing day, so all the other days were "shifted forward" by one. This meant that, for every day since 1/3/1900, the "actual day 1" was 31/12/1899 (or, if you prefer, day 0 was 30/12/1899). The Excel guys first used a small hack to make their functions behave exactly like Lotus 123 ones.

On the other hand, when VBA was added to Excel, the people responsible for the date/time functions in VBA decided to fix the whole thing in some way: instead of using 1/1/1900 as day 1 and faking the presence of 29/02/1900, they actually moved the epoch back of one day: the first two months of 1900 weren't compatible anymore with Lotus 123, but the system gained in coherency.

Source: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html