# How to format Stripe timestamp in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, stripe-payments

One of the fields I get back from a Stripe request is the created field, which contains the value "1351894331". I have tried using DateFormat() in Coldfusion to format this, but that did not work out. I imagine this is some sort of date type / timestamp that needs to be converted before DateFormatting it, but what do I need to use? What type of date format is that?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should not assume that everyone knows what "stripe" is.  Is it this: https://stripe.com/ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That could be a number of seconds from 1970-01-01?  This code:

```
<cfoutput>#dateAdd("s", 1351894331, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))#</cfoutput>
```

Outputs:

```
{ts '2012-11-02 21:12:11'}
```

Would that be around about the timestamp you'd expect?

Have you read the "Stripe" docs?  If I wanted to know how something worked, my first port of call would be to RTFM.  To put it appropriately, if slightly indelicately.

On a whim, I [googled "what format is stripe created timestamps in" for you](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what+format+is+stripe+created+timestamps+in). The first link goes to here.  The second link goes to [the relevant question on strip.com's docs](https://answers.stripe.com/questions/in-what-format-are-stripe-timestamps), which say:

> Yes, all Stripe times are in UTC represented as the Unix epoch.

And just to verify [the Unix Epoch date, I googled that too](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=unix+epoch+date). And the answer is:

> Unix time, [...] is [...] defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), 1 January 1970

Of course if you're meaning some other sort of "stripe", you're gonna have to elaborate.

Comment: Could also just use `createDate(1970,1,1)` to get the same value for the third argument.

Comment: @Adam Cameron: I did in fact read the docs and do a little Googling but obviously I wasn't able to arrive at the same solution you did. So I should probably quit programming then, right?

Comment: @AdamCameron: Thanks for the help on the solution, but not so much the life lesson. :)

Comment: Well hopefully you'll take something away from both, even if one was more welcomed than the other.  Stick with it, and remember Google is your friend.

Comment: In defense of the op, I've been told my Google-Fu is strong and I also had difficulty finding this information. Thanks Cheeky for posting this question and Adam for answering it!

Answer (score 5):

That's a unix timestamp - number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970 - which is used often as a method for storing dates.

But not in CFML, where dates are handled as a floating number of days since 30-Dec-1899.

To convert from a unix timestamp to a CF date number, you need to divide by number of seconds in a day (86400), then add the number of days between the two dates.

```
<cfset UnixTime = 1351894331 />

<!--- days between 1-Jan-1970 and 30-Dec-1899) --->
<cfset UnixTimeOffset = 25569 />

<cfset CfTime = UnixTimeOffset + UnixTime/86400 />
```

You can then use the `CfTime` variable in any date functions and they will work as usual.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The Cf OleDateTime class extends the java.util.Date class, which stores its value as seconds from epoch, aka January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. Where did you get 30th Dec 1899 from?

Comment: If you want to convert a unix timestamp from an integer to a cf date, you can use this: `myCfDate = createObject('java','coldfusion.runtime.OleDateTime').init(javaCast('long',1351894331 * 1000));` - you need to multiply your timestamp by 1000 - it means zero milliseconds

Comment: OleDateTime, when constructed with a Long, wraps it's super java.util.Date, as documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)

Comment: No, I'm not sure - I just plucked that date and the code example out of thin air. ¬_¬

http://cfg11n.blogspot.co.uk/2006/05/there-is-such-thing-as-timezone-hell.html
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/226-ColdFusion-Date-Math-Faster-Than-Date-Methods-And-Other-Date-Math-Ramblings.htm

Comment: I just had a look at the OleDateTime class's toDouble() method. It indeed uses: 25569 + millis + timezone offset / 86400000. Which would explain why JavaCast() returns that. Seems to be related to "OLE Automation date format" - google it. CF10 introduces UTCOleDateTime, which stores the time internally in the UTC tz, but when you interact with it, uses the server tz. Oh man...

Comment: "The OLE automation date format is a floating point value, counting days since midnight 30 December 1899. Hours and minutes are represented as fractional days." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714372/why-is-coldfusions-epoch-time-dec-30-1899

Answer (score 1):

Stripe is a supported gateway in CFPAYMENT (a well-tested library that helps you avoid writing e-commerce plumbing code) and has helper functions for the date conversions.  You can see the methods here:

https://github.com/ghidinelli/cfpayment/blob/master/api/gateway/stripe/stripe.cfc

```
<cffunction name="dateToUTC" output="false" access="public" returntype="any" hint="Take a date and return the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch">
    <cfargument name="date" type="any" required="true" />
    <cfreturn dateDiff("s", dateConvert("utc2Local", "January 1 1970 00:00"), arguments.date) />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="UTCToDate" output="false" access="public" returntype="date" hint="Take a UTC timestamp and convert it to a ColdFusion date object">
    <cfargument name="utcdate" required="true" />
    <cfreturn dateAdd("s", arguments.utcDate, dateConvert("utc2Local", "January 1 1970 00:00")) />
</cffunction>
```