# unable to understand the createdatetime usage

Tags: coldfusion

I have a timestamp which is in Linux Epoch Format. I am going through an existing code and I found the
following:

```
<cfset timestampVal  = 1337197600 />
<cfset NewTimeStampVal  = dateAdd("s", timestampVal, createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))/>
```

Looked at the Coldfusion Documentation for DateAdd and the syntax is `DateAdd("datepart", number, "date")`

So in my case, I have s for second, date in linux epoch format in place of number and I don't quite understand why `createDateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))` is required. I understand that Linux Epoch timestampformat is the time
in seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970. but unable to understand above part.

Answer (score 1):

Which part do you not understand?  You seem to already state the reason.

CF date does not start at Jan 1, 1970.  Therefore, you need to add the x seconds to that as the start date.

You may use `createDate()` instead and ignore the time.

```
<cfset timestampVal = 1337197600>
<cfset newTimeStampVal = dateAdd("s", timestampVal, createDate(1970, 1, 1))>
```

See: [why is ColdFusion's Epoch Time Dec 30, 1899?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714372/why-is-coldfusions-epoch-time-dec-30-1899)

Comment: If CF date doesn't start at Jan 1,1970, from where does it starts?

Comment: I still don't understand why we need to add x seconds.

Comment: Nothing in CF says you *have to* start from the Unix epoch. Whatever the reason, it is specific to your app. You would have to review the code, to find out more about why it is doing so ..

Comment: @user3558091 google what is Linux Epoch time and it's formula for converting into a datetime and then you will understand "why you need to add x seconds".