# Convert DOUBLE column to TIMESTAMP in Firebird database

Tags: sql, coldfusion, firebird

I have a Firebird database that saves the datetime field as a DOUBLE. I have created a ColdFusion datasource connection, so I can query the data remotely. While the rest of the data is being returned correctly, the datetime field is unreadable. I have tried using CAST and CONVERT to no avail. How can I convert this to a timestamp?

An example of the data stored is: `43016.988360`

Comment: try his link http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq314/

Comment: What do you expect the datetime of 43016.988360?

Comment: Even Microsoft Excel alone has THREE different methods of converting double to datetime. You have to investigate your program, that creates those databases, how it turns datetime into double, then you would have to do the reversed action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just convert a `DOUBLE PRECISION` to a `TIMESTAMP`, not without explicitly defining how you want it mapped and writing that conversion yourself (or hoping there is an existing third-party UDF that does this for you).

A `TIMESTAMP` in Firebird is a date + time represented as an 8 byte value, where the date range is from January 1, 1 a.d. to December 31, 9999 a.d. and the time range is 00:00 to 23:59.9999 (so, 100 microsecond precision).

A `DOUBLE PRECISION` is - usually - the wrong type for storing date and time information, and as you haven't provided how that double value should be interpreted, we can't help you other than saying: there is no default method in Firebird to do this.

Based on the comments below, it looks like the value is a ColdFusion date value stored as double precision with the number of days since December 30th 1899, see also [why is ColdFusion's Epoch Time Dec 30, 1899?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714372/why-is-coldfusions-epoch-time-dec-30-1899). If this is really the case, then you can use the following for conversion to a `TIMESTAMP`:

```
select timestamp'1899-12-30 00:00' + 43016.988360 from rdb$database
```

Which will yield the value 2017-10-08 23:43:14.304. Using the value `43182.4931754` from the comments will yield 2018-03-23 11:50:10.354. That is a millisecond off from your expectation, but that might be a rounding/presentation issue, eg I get the exact expected date if I use `43182.49317539` instead.

I would strongly suggest you carefully test this with known values.

Comment: @AnthonyDoherty Yeah, and that is meaningless if you don't specify how that double value should be converted to a date time value. What is the unit, what is its epoch? As âńōŋŷXmoůŜ already commented, what date do you expect to get for `43016.988360`, and more importantly how would you derive that date?! A `DOUBLE PRECISION` is just a binary floating point (a numerical value), it has no date/time related meaning. Just like for example the 64 bit `long` value from Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` only has meaning because it is specified as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: Thanks folks, its a 3rd party system and i'm trying to just extract data from the DB - I have already emailed the developers but they are reluctant to get back to me.
I have managed to work out that 43182.4931754 so equate to 2018-03-23 11:50:10.353, but if i was to use this command select CAST(43182.4931754 as datetime) it is converting it to the 25th not the 23

Comment: @AnthonyDoherty For example, if we assume an epoch of 1900-01-01 00:00, and the unit to be days (which is one of the ways Excel uses), then the date could be 2017-10-10 23:43:14.304; you could calculate that using `timestamp'1900-01-01 00:00' + 43016.988360`, but if the epoch and/or unit is different you'll get a totally different result.

Comment: @AnthonyDoherty If I apply the epoch and unit in my previous comment with that value of `43182.4931754`, then I get 2018-03-25 11:50:10.354. BTW: Firebird doesn't have a `datetime` type, so that cast should fail with an exception).

Comment: @AnthonyDoherty Looking at this question [why is ColdFusion's Epoch Time Dec 30, 1899?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714372/why-is-coldfusions-epoch-time-dec-30-1899), this might mean that my comment could be the answer, but you'll need to use `1899-12-30 00:00` as the epoch (as that will yield the value you expected (with a millisecond differences, which is a precision issue). However I'd strongly suggest you'd test that carefully for a range of known values.

Comment: Yes I was taking the value and using the CAST command in SSMS.  i've rang the developers asking how the date is converted and will update when they come back to me.  Thanks

Comment: OK, got speaking to developers and they said to just copy it into excel and format it (not very helpful mind you) but I asked for the base date and they told me it was 1899-12-30 00:00:00.
So do i take my field into SQL and cast it as date then minus 2 days from it??

Comment: @AnthonyDoherty See my update answer. You can use `timestamp'1899-12-30 00:00' + <double value>`

Comment: "just copy it into excel and format it" - LOL. Different versions of Excel on different platforms use three different origin points.... But okay, at least that gives you the reference point. Frankly, there was another way to hack the system. ASSUMING the value counts full days in integer part and in-day time in fractional part (which is reasonable and frequent but not the only possible scheme) you could change the value in the database to zero, then put this database back to the program and see how the program would represent 0.0 as date, what is the base point.

Comment: And may I add, once you have the date value, use ColdFusion to format it. No need to do it in the database itself.

Comment: @DavidFaber Unless of course the OP is trying to do something with the data in the Firebird databases outside of ColdFusion.